# How to correctly understand the positions of ontological nihilism?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, nihilism

Lately I have been investigating ontological nihilism. However, different sources give completely different definitions of this philosophical position, which I have divided into two main groups.

1. The first group says that individual objects and concepts do not actually exist. Something exists that we perceive as separate objects and concepts, but in fact, everything that exists is something that is not reduced to separate objects and concepts. Such a position is quite acceptable, it can be consistent, as far as I understand.
2. The second group claims that nothing exists at all. There are no objects, no ideas, not even the consciousness of the one who makes this statement. Absolutely nothing exists. This position seems contradictory to me, because something that we call consciousness still somehow exists, if at the moment I think about it and come to this conclusion.

I am not a philosopher, and may well be misunderstanding all the arguments. I would be glad to know the opinion of more experienced participants.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137331/discussion-on-question-by---how-to-correctly-understand-the-positio).